# How to show a improper integral is convergent by using Taylor expansion?

Tags: improper-integrals

How do I show that the following improper integral $$\int^1_0\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2\sqrt{x}}dx$$ is convergent by using Taylor expansion rigorously?

So $e^x=1+x+x^2/2+x^3B(x)$ where $B(x)$ bounded close to zero. It doesn't make sense to just insert this in the integral directly. But maybe the following works? There exists a $\delta>0$  such that $\int^\delta_0\frac{1+x+x^2/2+x^3B(x)-1-x}{x^2\sqrt{x}}dx=\int^\delta_0\frac{1/2}{\sqrt{x}}+\sqrt{x}B(x)dx$ which is convergent since $B(x)$ is bounded.

Comment: The problem arises near the $0$ bound, since there is there a division by zero. You have to find an equivalent of the integrand, and then you will know whether the integral is convergent. What you have done works too.

Comment: You could use the following on $[0,\,1]$:$$\frac12\le\frac12+\frac16x+\cdots=\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}\le e-2,$$since the Taylor series is increasing as it has positive coefficients. Now bound your integral between multiples of $\int_0^1x^{-1/2}dx$.